# How to understand the DC-biasing and the HPF circuits in the top-left corner of OPA1671 datasheet's reference application schematic?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm looking to understand the chosen values in this reference design and whether they can be improved, particularly the biasing DC circuit and the high-pass filter for the electret microphone.

[image: Reference application schematic of OPA1671 from TI]

My understanding is that these two circuits can be analyzed via superposition.

Taking the DC biasing circuit first, we'd get something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftD0Ys.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I assume that R1 and C1 form a LPF, with a cutoff frequency of ~10 Hz; is that correct? If it is, then that would make sense, however, I'm not completely sure how to interpret C2 as a part of this circuit - in steady-state, this should be an open path (and then we can ignore C1 as well), which leads to 2 voltage dividers -> R1 || R2 and then ((R1 || R2) || (R3 || R4)). I can understand that R3 and R4 are chosen to be the same value to divide the supply voltage in half at the input of the op-amp, hence the DC biasing. I don't understand why R2 was put there or, at the very least, given a value of 10k, since that loads down the second divider and the DC voltage at the input of the op-amp is actually around ~2.15V. Would it make sense to increase R2 here to have a more equal biasing point?

With regards to the high-pass filter, my question is still the same - what's the point of R2 here? The C2 and R3||R4 form an HPF with a pole at 3.18 Hz, as described in this datasheet. This seems to form a pi-network, but I'm not sure why that'd be needed? Is it to limit the input current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvziS9.png)</sup>

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, there is not just one way of making a microphone amplifier, and this circuit is only an example, and while any circuit can be improved by changing component values to be more suitable for a specific case you might have, a different circuit might be better to begin with, so there is no point trying to optimize a generic example.

The R1 and C1 do form a 10 Hz low-pass filter, and the filtered output supply is used to power/bias the microphone capsule itself and the non-inverting input of the op-amp.

From then on, your analysis starts to go haywire.

The microphone can't be replaced by a short circuit to ground. At mininum, it should be replaced by a resistor to ground, or a constant current sink, to evaluate DC bias.

The microphone needs a bias supply, and it needs it via a resistor to a power supply, as the microphone has a JFET output stage built-in. So the resistor R2 is to give a bias supply to the microphone, from the filtered supply. The value of R2 is not very important here, and it is likely chosen at random, or just considered a roughly suitablr value for that specific microphone, or a wide range of different microphones. Usually the bias resistor is approximately 2 kohms to approximately 2 volts to provide some bias current at some bias voltage to the mic, but since the supply is almost 5V the resistor can be higher and it would cause relatively lower bias voltage to the mic but also mic output current chages would cause larger output voltage swings.

So, basically, R2 and mic provide you an audio signal with a DC bias.

Now, the DC bias out of the mic should be removed to let the resistor divider R3 and R4 to set the amplifier input bias to half supply. The bias is removed by C2. The value just needs to be good enough to pass audio. The input impedance to amplifier is 50 kohms. The 1uF cap with 50k impedance calculates to a roughly 3 Hz high pass - it will pass audio band just fine and removes DC bias. In reality you would need to calculate it with the mic output impedance which is max 10k, so it would not really change anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I completely disregarded the fact that a microphone is not an ideal AC voltage source. My goal here is to build a bit more intuition with circuit analysis and I was happy I recognized common elements from a different app-note in this datasheet; the only thing I'm not quite sure now is with regards to R2 in the first schematic I added - will C2 have the voltage difference between the bias voltage (say, it's 1V) and half of the supply voltage (2.5V) on it then?

Comment: Voltage over R2 depends on how much bias current mic takes. Thus C2 will have any voltage over it based on mic bias. There will always be about 2.5V at op-amp input, although slightly less, due to bias current of mic and current through op-amp input divider, which will drop current over R1.